# Intuition behind double integrals of p.d.f. of two random variables to compare them

Tags: probability, integration

I came across following point:

> There are two random variable representing two cars. We pick the car which is most efficient. The probability with which we pick a car is our belief that it is the most efficient. For example, if Cars $C=\{c_1,c_2\}$, the probability of picking a car $c_1$ is $$\mathbb{P}\{x_1>x_2\}=\int_{x_1=0}^1\int_{x_2=0}^{x_1}p(x_1)p(x_2)dx_2dx_1$$, where $p(x_i)$ is a p.d.f. of distribution representing our belief that $c_i$ is the most efficient.

My doubt is what is the intuition behind using double intergral for comparing two random variables to choose one among them.

PS.: That quote is somewhat my interpretation of what the text means to say out of long paragraph. So, I might make some mistake there.

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong with the translator,  "We pick the car which is most." is not a complete sentence.  And I am guessing that "pick an arm" is meant to read "pick a car".  But, regardless of the details:  the double integral appears to assume that the two ratings are independent (so you don't change your view of $c_1$ based on what you feel about $c_2$ and conversely).  So the joint probability distribution is the product $P(x_1,x_2)=p(x_1)p(x_2)$

Answer (score 1):

I think your sentence should have been:

> We pick the car which is **the most efficient**

Now as the effciency is a % its domain is of course $\in [0;1]$

so, assuming independence between the variables (I named them X and Y) the requested probability is the integral of their joint density over the purple area below

[image]

say

$$\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\int_{0}^{1}p_X(x)\Bigg[\int_{0}^{x}p_Y(y)dy\Bigg]dx$$